# Error: Transaction rejected with non-error: undefined

Tags: node.js, oracle, knex.js

I am using knex npm version 0.15.2. while Rollback the transaction I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Transaction rejected with non-error: undefined

```
Trx.rollback()
```

above function used for rollback.

Same code working for knex version 0.12.6

This is the function I used for commit/Rollback.

```
function Commit(pTrx, pIsCommit, pCallback) {
    try {
        var co = require("co");
        var q = require('q');
        var Q = q.defer();
        co(function* () {
            if (pIsCommit) {
                yield pTrx.commit();
            } else {
                yield pTrx.rollback();
            }
            Q.resolve(pCallback('SUCCESS'));
        }).catch(function (error) {
            Q.reject(pCallback(error));
        });
        return Q.promise;
    } catch (error) {
     console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: if the transaction was already committed, execute some dml operation wtth same connection may got this error.

Answer (score 3):

This code could use some work. :) Here are a few things that pop out:

- You don't need `co` or `q` anymore. Promises and async/await are built-in and much simpler to use. Async functions automatically return promises that will be resolved with the value returned or rejected if an error is thrown. Learn about async/await here: https://jsao.io/2017/07/how-to-get-use-and-close-a-db-connection-using-async-functions/
- You shouldn't return success as a string. If the function completes without throwing an exception, then success is implied. I see people do this from time to time, but it's often for the wrong reasons.
- You shouldn't accept callback in a function that returns a promise, it should be one or the other. The caller of your function will either pass a callback or await it's completion.
- If you are going to use callbacks, then you should return `null` as the first parameter when successful. See the last sentence here: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/
- Your function name, Commit, starts with an uppercase. This convention is typically used to indicate that the function is a contstructor function and meant to be invoked with the `new` keyword.

Here's how the function could look once cleaned up:

```
async function commit(pTrx, pIsCommit) {
  // Not using a try/catch. If an error is thrown the promise returned will be rejected.
  if (pIsCommit) {
    await pTrx.commit();
  } else {
    await pTrx.rollback();
  }
  // Not going to return anything. If we get to this point then success is implied when the promise is resolved.
}
```

A consumer of your function would call it with something like:

```
async function myWork() {
  // do work; get pTrx

  try {
    await commit(pTrx, true);
    // If I get here, then I can assume commit was successful, no need to check a return value of 'SUCCESS'
  } catch (err) {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

It's hard to say where the issue is with the code in its current state. However, if the issue truly is with Knex, then you should probably post this as an issue in the Knex repo: https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues But you should write a reproducible test case that proves its an issue with Knex.